# Spring Data Neo4j and transactions in chained services

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I have a service for example

```
public class ServiceA {

    @Transactional
    public void a() {
        ...
        serviceB.b()
        ...
    }
}
```

that calls a method of another service

```
public class ServiceB {

    @Transactional
    public void b() {
        ...
        graphRepository.save(..)
        ...
    }
}
```

that calls a method of a GraphRepository.

If there isn't any problem during the execution of the GraphRepository method everithigs works well, but if an exception occurs in the GraphRepository the rollback doesn't work and all calls to the remote db are blocked.

If I remove the Transactional annotation over the b() everithins works well even if an exception occurs in the GraphRepository.

I can't explain this behavior.

Can you help me?

Comment: Is that SDN 4x or 3x ?

Comment: And embedded or remote?

Comment: SDN 4x amd remote server

Comment: Could you try with the neo4j-ogm 1.1.5-SNAPSHOT?  Some issues around this area were fixed. <dependency>
                <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>neo4j-ogm</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.5-SNAPSHO</version>
            </dependency> You'll need to also include    <repository>
            <id>neo4j-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to [Luanne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/232671/luanne) and her comment I solved the issue

This is a bug and it is solved in neo4j-ogm 1.1.5-SNAPSHOT